# How to find form of Linear differential equation if fundamental system of solutions is given

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

$$e^x, e^{2x},...,e^{nx}$$ - fundamental system of solutions of Linear differential equation. How to find form of Linear differential equation?

---

I've read that we need to do next (Wronskian):
$$A_{n}=\begin{bmatrix}
y(x)&e^x&e^{2x}& \cdots &e^{nx}\\
y'(x)&e^x&2e^{2x}& \cdots &ne^{nx}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
y^{(n)}(x)&e^x&2^{n}e^{2x}& \cdots &n^{n}e^{nx}\end{bmatrix}=0$$
and then make Laplace expansion along the first column yields.
We will have 
$$y(x)*det_1+y'(x)*det_2+...+y^{(n)}(x)*det_n=0$$
But how to find det1, det2,..,detn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential equation $y^{(n)} + a_{n-1} y^{(n-1)} + \ldots + a_0 y = 0$ has solution $e^{r x}$ if $r$ is a root of the polynomial $r^n + a_{n-1} r^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0$.  So we just need to find a polynomial whose roots are $1, \ldots, n$: namely
$(r - 1)(r-2) \ldots (r-n)$.

The coefficients turn out to be signed Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your eigenvalues are

$\lambda_k=k$. The characteristic polynomial is given by

$$P(\lambda)=(\lambda-\lambda_1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (\lambda-\lambda_n).$$

Use the theorem of Vieta to obtain the coefficients of

$$P(\lambda)=\lambda^n+a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0.$$

The differential equation is given as:

$$y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\ldots+a_0=0.$$